# Clojure: alternative to a2ps on OSX?

Tags: printing, clojure

### Context

Sometimes, I like reading code on paper rather than on screen (so I can scribble / write on them.) On linux, I just use a2ps.

### Question

Currently, I'm on OSX. What is a good tool for taking a bunch of *.clj files, and convering them into readable *.pdf/*.ps files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure what your definition of readable is, but you could use [Pygments](http://pygments.org/) to convert the code to syntax-highlighted HTML and then either print that out directly or use another tool like [Pandoc](http://johnmacfarlane.net/pandoc/) to convert it to PDF. (You can also use Pygments to convert to LaTeX and then convert that to PDF.)

Also, some quick googling turns up [this blogpost](http://boklee.blogspot.com/2012/05/enscript-alternative-to-a2ps-in-os-x.html), which suggests that the GNU utility [enscript](https://www.gnu.org/software/enscript/) can be installed somehow (possibly via MacPorts). I'm not able to test this though.

Answer (score 0):

I found some [Clojure highlighting support for GNU Enscript](http://blog.mired.org/2010/08/syntax-highlighting-for-clojure-code.html) from Mike Meyer.

It seems to work great.

[image]